# Azure Data Factory - querying Cosmos DB using dynamic timestamps

Tags: azure-data-factory

I want to create and maintain a snapshot of a collection in Cosmos DB.

Periodically, I want to retrieve only the delta (new or modified documents) from Cosmos and write them to the snapshot, which will be stored in a Azure Data Explorer cluster.

I wish to get the delta using the _ts member of the documents. In other words, I will fetch only records for which the _ts is between some range.

The range will be the range of a time window, which I get using a tumbling window trigger in the data factory.

The issue is that if I print the dynamic timestamps which I create in the query, and hard code them into the query, it works. But if I let the query generate them, I don't get any results.

For example:

I'm using those value to simulate the window range of the trigger.

[image]

I use this query to create timestamps in unix time.

[image]

and I see that the timestamps created are correct.

[image]

And if I run my query using those hardcoded timestamps, I get results

[image]

But, if I run a query using the code that just create those timestamps, I get no results from the query

[image]

This is the code to create the timestamps:

```
select 
DateTimeToTimestamp('@{formatDateTime('2020-05-20T12:00:00.0000000Z','yyyy-MM
ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')}')/1000,
DateTimeToTimestamp('@{formatDateTime('2020-08-20T12:00:00.0000000Z','yyyy-MM
ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')}')/1000
```

Does anyone have a clue as to what might be the issue?

Any other way to achieve this is also welcome.

Thanks

EDIT: I managed to work around this by taking the other, simpler option:

```
where TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000)> "@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')}"
```

Comment: Hi Tylor, just from you new edit, have you solved it by the simpler option?

Comment: Yes, but still curious what is wrong with the first option.

Comment: Congratulations that you solved the issue. I just help you post it as the answer instead of put it in the edit. You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Just from your query code, I think it's caused by the different data type.

Answer (score 0):

We are glad that you resolved this problem:

You managed to work around this by taking the other, simpler option:

```
where TimestampToDateTime(c._ts*1000)> "@{formatDateTime(pipeline().parameters.windowStart,'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')}"
```

I think the error in first option is most caused by the different data type between `c.ts` and `DateTimeToTimestamp('@{formatDateTime('2020-05-20T12:00:00.0000000Z','yyyy-MM ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ')}')/1000`.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? what is the difference? which types are they? how can I convert from on to the other?

Comment: what's the data type of c.ts?